# Using APEX collection with query in hidden object, get ORA-06550/PLS-00103 error

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I haven't been able to find this issue in other threads, so hoping it's something simple. The code worked last month, and now is broken.

```
DECLARE
    l_query varchar2(32767) := &QUERY1. || &QUERY2.;
    cond_var varchar2(200) := ' 1 = 1 ';
begin
    IF APEX_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_EXISTS (p_collection_name => 'CHILDREN') THEN
            APEX_COLLECTION.DELETE_COLLECTION (p_collection_name => 'CHILDREN');
    end if;
    APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY_B (
        p_collection_name => 'CHILDREN', 
        p_query => l_query);
End;
```

I get the error in the `l_query` definition at the ampersand. `QUERY1/2` are hidden page items that hold the text of those queries, and I have to concatenate them because of character limits on those page items (the query is large).

Am I referencing those hidden page items incorrectly? If not, how can I access them/why might this have changed recently?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "hidden objects" you mean hidden page items (or application items) then use bind syntax:

```
l_query varchar2(32767) := :QUERY1 || :QUERY2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response (and terminology correction - I'll update the questio), but that also gives an error (ORA-20001) and suggests v() syntax if over 30 bytes (and each of those are much larger than 30 bytes). When I convert it to v() syntax, it appears to not actually reference what's in the object and gives another 20001 error (query must begin with select or with). Which is, I suspect, why I used the & notation to begin with.

Comment: Do you mean your item **names** are more than 30 bytes long?  Because certainly the content of a page item can be much, much longer than that.  If it is the item names then I would suggest you simply use shorter names.

Comment: No, I just mistyped (left the period in, and then APEX said it couldn't bind because I didn't ask it to do it correctly). However, with bind syntax I get the same error as with v() syntax (query must begin with select or with). Pasted error: ORA-20104: create_collection_from_query_b Error:ORA-20001: Query must begin with SELECT or WITH

Comment: My issue there was another artifact of the ampersand syntax, where the query had to be enclosed in quotes that I did not address. Thank you very much for your help!